# NSInvalidArgumentException NSDictionary count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, categories

i have write a NSDictionary Category. The Category has a method calls "initWithJSONURL".
Here the code:

```
- (id)initWithJSONURL:(NSURL *)url
{
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    NSError *error;

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                         options:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                           error:&error];

    if (!data) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"connection failed"
                                                        message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else {
        self = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                               options:0
                                                 error:&error];

        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"invalid data"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }

    }

}

return self;
}
```

And here the code from my ViewController viewDidLoad

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/json.php"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithJSONURL:url];
NSLog(@"%@", dict);
```

If I use an correct URL everything works perfect.
But if the URL not correct, the App crash.
I don't know why, it should not crash, it should show the alert View.
The consoles show:

```
erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary count]: method sent to an uninitialized immutable dictionary object'
```

I hope anybody can help me and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: 1st thing - the line `if (error) {` should be `if (!self) {`. Never check the error without first checking the return value of the method that might give an error. 2nd thing - If `data` is `nil`, you should set `self` to `nil`.

Comment: You need to rethink your code. You shouldn't be assigning something new to `self` inside of your `init` method. Or ever, really.

Comment: That code is terrible, by the way. Just calling a blocking URL request (even on localhost) from `viewDidLoad` is terrible. The entire logic in the category is terrible.

Comment: @Gavin - actually this pattern is not too bad. Many of Apple's class clusters will do stuff like this internally. But personally I would have made this a class level helper method, not an instance method.

Comment: @Gavin: I do not think that you are correct. Assigning to `self` is allowed exactly in  `init` methods. And an initializer is not required to return the object from the delegate init call.

Comment: @rmaddy As Sulthan points out, however, it's bad for other reasons.

Comment: @Gavin I agree it has its issues but reassigning `self` is far from the worst.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I'm aware it's allowed. But most of the time it should be avoided unless you have a very good reason. And there's no reason to do it here, it's just wasting CPU cycles to allocate memory and then throw it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call `[self init]` instead of `[super init]`. A category is not a subclass, so `[super init]` means `[NSObject init]`. The designated initializer of `NSDictionary` is never called and the internal dictionary structures are staying unitiliazed.

Comment: Nice. Also is it just me or will the 2nd attempt at doing `self =` result in an error since this is an immutable NSDictionary?

Comment: @Madbreaks Why? Assigning to a variable doesn't have anything to do with immutability.

Comment: @Madbreaks It won't result in an error, but it's really bad code. If this were pre-ARC, the original self would leak for one thing. I would assume ARC handles it correctly, but it's still really bad to do.

Comment: @Gavin There are many situations when this is useful. Class clusters  are one example. But you have to know what you are doing.

Comment: @Sulthan Yes, that is one of the few cases where it makes sense. Here, it makes no sense.